# is there builtins in ojdbc for constants of DBMS_METADATA package?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, dbms-metadata

package Oracle [DBMS_METADATA](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_metadata.html) contain Object Type Constants

```
AQ_QUEUE    REF_CONSTRAINT
AQ_QUEUE_TABLE  REFRESH_GROUP
AQ_TRANSFORM    RESOURCE_COST
ASSOCIATION ....
```

I want program in java using this constants and want avoid code duplication if possible.

is there builtins in ojdbc for constants of DBMS_METADATA package?

Something like enums or `public static final String` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself: no buildins for this